# Succinctly rewrite a set of functions with variable number of arguments

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic

I am trying to figure out a cleaner way of writing this rather ugly code:

```
class PythonExtensionBase : public PyObject
{
:
public:
    // helper functions to call function fn_name with 0 to 9 args
    Object callOnSelf( const std::string &fn_name );
    Object callOnSelf( const std::string &fn_name, const Object &arg1 );
    Object callOnSelf( const std::string &fn_name, const Object &arg1, const Object &arg2 );
    Object callOnSelf( const std::string &fn_name, const Object &arg1, const Object &arg2, const Object &arg3 );
    :
```

(all the way up to 9)

These functions are implemented in the corresponding .cxx:

```
Py::Object PythonExtensionBase::callOnSelf( const std::string &fn_name )
{
    Py::TupleN args;
    return  self().callMemberFunction( fn_name, args );
}

Py::Object PythonExtensionBase::callOnSelf( const std::string &fn_name,
                                            const Py::Object &arg1 )
{
    Py::TupleN args( arg1 );
    return  self().callMemberFunction( fn_name, args );
}

Py::Object PythonExtensionBase::callOnSelf( const std::string &fn_name,
                                            const Py::Object &arg1, const Py::Object &arg2 )
{
    Py::TupleN args( arg1, arg2 );
    return self().callMemberFunction( fn_name, args );
}

Py::Object PythonExtensionBase::callOnSelf( const std::string &fn_name,
                                            const Py::Object &arg1, const Py::Object &arg2, const Py::Object &arg3 )
{
    Py::TupleN args( arg1, arg2, arg3 );
    return self().callMemberFunction( fn_name, args );
}
:
```

Effectively the task is to generalise:

```
X( A a, B b1, B b2, B b3 ) {
    foo( b1, b2, b3 );
}
```

I can see that a variadic template is probably the way to go, but I'm struggling to understand how to use it.

That TupleN class is defined as follows:

```
class TupleN: public Tuple
{
public:
    TupleN()
    : Tuple( 0 )
    {
    }

    TupleN( const Object &obj1 )
    : Tuple( 1 )
    {
        setItem( 0, obj1 );
    }

    TupleN( const Object &obj1, const Object &obj2 )
    : Tuple( 2 )
    {
        setItem( 0, obj1 );
        setItem( 1, obj2 );
    }

    TupleN( const Object &obj1, const Object &obj2, const Object &obj3 )
    : Tuple( 3 )
    {
        setItem( 0, obj1 );
        setItem( 1, obj2 );
        setItem( 2, obj3 );
    }

    :

    virtual ~TupleN()
    { }
};
```

Comment: I sincerely hope the only reason for this is because the author originally had no availability of C++11 features. If that is indeed the case and said-problem has since been resolved, a great deal of this can indeed be scrapped for a variadic solution.

Comment: Alternatively to variadic solution, you may use `std::initializer_list<Object>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you'd use a variadic template:

```
template <class... Arg>
Object callOnSelf( const std::string &fn_name, Arg&&... arg )
{
    Py::TupleN args(std::forward<Arg>(arg)...);
    return  self().callMemberFunction( fn_name, args );
}
```

The problem with variadic templates is that you cannot restrict them to work with "a variadic number of arguments *of a particular type."* You can either leave it as is (and get compilation errors from the `TupleN` constructor), or you can help it slightly with a static assert and a helper:

```
template <class Car, class... Cdr>
struct isObject
{
  static constexpr bool value = isObject<Car> && isObject<Cdr...>::value;
};

template <class T>
struct isObject<T>
{
  static constexpr bool value = std::is_convertible<const T&, const Py::Object&>::value;
};

template <class... Arg>
Object callOnSelf( const std::string &fn_name, Arg&&... arg )
{
    static_assert(isObject<Arg...>::value, "All arguments to callOnSelf must be PyObject compatible");
    Py::TupleN args(std::forward<Arg>(arg)...);
    return  self().callMemberFunction( fn_name, args );
}
```

---

As for the `TupleN` class, you can do a similar trick:

```
class TupleN: public Tuple
{
public:
    template <class Arg...>
    TupleN(Arg&&... arg)
    : Tuple( sizeof...(arg))
    {
      setItems(0, std::forward<Arg>(arg)...);
    }

private:
    template <class Car, class... Cdr>
    void setItems(size_t idx, Car&& car, Cdr&&... cdr) {
      setItem(idx, std::forward<Car>(car));
      setItems(idx + 1, std::forward<Cdr>(cdr)...);
    }

    void setItems(size_t)  // recursion terminator
    {}
};
```

Comment: @RichardHodges Almost. Beat you by a minute :-)

Comment: Thanks for both answers :) How might I tidy up the TupleN class, which currently suffers the same ugly duplication?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a variadic template argument.

```
template<class...Args>
Py::Object PythonExtensionBase::callOnSelf( const std::string &fn_name,
                                            Args&&...args_ )
{
    Py::TupleN args( std::forward<Args>(args_)... );
    return self().callMemberFunction( fn_name, args );
}
```

update: but why pass args_ as an rvalue reference?

answer: perfect forwarding.

consider:

```
struct X { }; // an expensive to copy object

foo(X {});  // call with a temporary
```

suppose foo hands off it's argument to some other inner function

```
void foo(X x)  // copied
{
  inner_foo(x);
}
```

and that inner_foo further passes the X on to a worker

```
void inner_foo(X x) // copied
{
  really_inner_foo(x); // copied again
}
```

You'd want to avoid all those copies, right? X might even be a type that's not copyable.

The way you'd write this in the specific case of passing an X is:

```
void foo(X x) {
  inner_foo(std::move(x));
}
```

and you could increase efficiency (by avoiding any moves at all):

```
template<class X_LIKE>
void foo(X_LIKE&& x) {
  inner_foo(std::forward<X_LIKE>(x));
}
```

Because an r-value reference will bind to an l-value reference if it needs to and thus it's perfectly permissible to pass a const ref to X:

```
const X x;
foo(x);
```

foo then effectively becomes:

```
void foo(const X& x) {
  inner_foo(x); // calls the const X& version of inner_foo
}
```

So in the general template form we pass by r-value reference and use std::forward<> because this construct perfectly preserves what was passed. If you pass a reference, it's passed as a reference all the way through. If you pass an object, it's passed as an r-value until the very last moment where it's used.

If you'd like to know more, do a google search for 'perfect forwarding' and prepare to have your mind blown :-)

Comment: I'm starting to see it!  Could you explain the double &&?

Comment: @Pi updated answer. convo me if you want to know more.